# Rerendering new page data on client after new API fetch on same route

Tags: api, client, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I have a search input in my Navbar that sends the user to the a `search/[searchTerm` page in the `+page.server.ts` that then uses the term is entered as the dynamic route param and as a search term in an API endpoint and then displays the data fetched on the `+page.svelte`.

**My issue is, once on the the `search/[searchTerm]` page that is displaying the data, when I try another search the `+page.server.ts` load function is ran again, the dynamic route param is updated, and the new data is fetched on the server, but on the client side the data is not updating and is still showing the results from the first search.** Is there a way to make the Page Data reactive? I have tried `$:` on the page data but the client data will not change.

`+page.server.ts`:

```
export const load: ServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {

    const searchTerm: string | undefined = params.searchTerm;

    const fetchSearchResults = async (searchTerm: string | undefined) => {
        const response = await getSearchResults(searchTerm);
        const results = await response.json();
        // console.log(results.albums.items);
        return results;
    };
    return {
        results: fetchSearchResults(searchTerm)
    };
};
```

Script of my +page.svelte:

```
export let data: PageData;

const { items } = data.results.albums;

const albums = items.slice(0, 10).map((album: any) => ({
    artist: album.artists.map((_artist: any) => _artist.name).join(', '),
    songUrl: album.external_urls.spotify,
    title: album.name,
    coverImage: album.images[2].url
}));
```

Search input on the navbar:

```
<form action={`/search/${searchTerm.split(' ').join('+')}`}>
    <input
        bind:value={searchTerm}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search…"
    />
    <button type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>
```

I have tried to deconstruct the param reactively

```
$: ({ items } = data.results.albums);
```

but that returns `items` as undefined.

Comment: I do not see any reason why `items` would be undefined when it isn't in the `const` case. How did you determine that?

Comment: I console logged ```items``` and it is undefined.

Comment: I have gone thought this twitter thread from Geoff Rich but all the variations he suggested still don't result in reactive page data from server. https://twitter.com/geoffrich_/status/1564297325002227713?lang=en

Comment: Disregard that, I didn't try the one that finally worked: https://twitter.com/geoffrich_/status/1564297339946553346

Answer (score 3):

After reading through Geoff Rich's twitter thread about this: https://twitter.com/geoffrich_/status/1564297339946553346

The solution that worked for me was to deconstruct the variable twice:

```js
let { items } = data.results.albums;

$: ({ items } = data.results.albums);
```

And also declare my `albums` variable as reactive:

```js
$: albums = items.slice(0, 10).map((album: any) => ({
    artist: album.artists.map((_artist: any) => _artist.name).join(', '),
    songUrl: album.external_urls.spotify,
    title: album.name,
    coverImage: album.images[2].url
}));
```

Comment: If your only use of `items` is in the `$: albums = ...` reactive statement, you'd be better off not destructuring at all and just use `$: albums = data.results.albums.items.slice(0, 10).map(...)` (the first option suggested by Geoff in his thread).